# Is it possible to install Nvidia + Ati (amd) graphics drivers on same pendrive system?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ati

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on a pendrive. Now I want to install graphics drivers. The problem is I'm launching this system on a few PCs. One is a laptop with Radeon, and others PCs got Nvidia cards. **Is is possible to install both graphics drivers on same pendrive system?**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:    13.04
Codename:   raring

$ lspci | grep VGA
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RC410M [Mobility Radeon Xpress 200M]
```